# Trim Leading 0's from DataFrame in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataframe :

```
 | subcategory | subcategory_label | category  |
 | 00EEE       | 00EEE FFF         | Drink     |
 | 0000EEE     | 00EEE FFF         | Fruit     |
 | 0EEE        | 000EEE FFF        | Meat      |
```

from which I need to remove leading 0's from the columns in Dataframe and need a result like this

```
| subcategory | subcategory_label | category  |
| EEE         | EEE FFF           | Drink     |
| EEE         | EEE FFF           | Fruit     |
| EEE         | EEE FFF           | Meat      |
```

So far, I am able to remove the leading 0's from one column using

```
df.withColumn("subcategory ", regexp_replace(df("subcategory "), "^0*", "")).show
```

How to remove the leading 0's from dataframe in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this as the provided dataframe :

```
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|subcategory|subcategory_label|category|
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|0000FFFF   |0000EE 000FF     |ABC     |
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
```

You can create a `regexp_replace` for all the columns. Something like :

```
val regex_all = df.columns.map( c => regexp_replace(col(c), "^0*", "" ).as(c) )
```

And then, use `select` since it takes a varargs of type `Column` :

```
df.select(regex_all :_* ).show(false)
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|subcategory|subcategory_label|category|
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|FFFF       |EE 000FF         |ABC     |
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
```

---

EDIT:

Defining a function to do return a `regexp_replace`d Sequence is straight forward :

```
/**
  * @param origCols total cols in the DF, pass `df.columns`
  * @param replacedCols `Seq` of columns for which expression is to be generated
  * @return `Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]` Spark SQL expression
  */
def createRegexReplaceZeroes(origCols : Seq[String], replacedCols: Seq[String] ) = {
    origCols.map{ c => 
        if(replacedCols.contains(c)) regexp_replace(col(c), "^0*", "" ).as(c) 
        else col(c)
    }
}
```

This function will return an `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]`

Now, store the columns you want to replace in an Array :

```
val removeZeroes = Array( "subcategory", "subcategory_label" )
```

And, then call the function with `removeZeroes` as argument. This will return the `regexp_replace` statements for the columns available in `removeZeroes`

```
df.select( createRegexReplaceZeroes(df.columns, removeZeroes) :_* )
```

Comment: so it will trim the 0's from all columns ?

Comment: Yes Do you have a specific set of columns from which you want to remove the `0`s?

Comment: apologies,if I need to remove from specific columns ,for example If I need to remove 0's from "subcategory" and "subcategory_label" only

Comment: You can just create an array with the columns that you need to replace. `val replaceThese = Array("subcategory" , "subcategory_label")` and then use `replaceThese.map(x => ...)` as stated in the answer.

Comment: thanks,is it possible if I can make function of this in Scala and use it anywhere in my code ,instead of writing it again and again

Comment: what,I am trying to say that:writing a function which will remove the zero's from specific columns and remaining columns remains same

Comment: ohh.........this is really very helpful,many thanks for this useful information.But the statement "df.select( createRegexReplaceZeroes(removeZeroes) :_* )" will only give the columns from which I need to remove the leading 0's (in the above example the Trim column will be ""subcategory", "subcategory_label").I need to return the Trim column as well non trim column from the function .The required output of the function should be like {subcategory(Trim) subcategory_Label(Trim) Category(Non Trim)}.Can you please help me

Comment: See edit again. try to add all this information in the question from the next time. Avoid commenting on the post now as I will not entertain any more edits. Ask a new question if you have problem with the code. Accept the answer if you don't.

Comment: I have run the program and it is giving compilation error

Comment: not found: value col
[error]       if(replacedCols.contains(c)) regexp_replace(col(c), "^0*", "" ).as(c)
[error]                                                   ^

Answer (score 0):

You can use UDF for doing the same.
I feel it looks more elegant.

```
scala> val removeLeadingZerosUDF = udf({ x: String => x.replaceAll("^0*", "") })
removeLeadingZerosUDF: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> val df = Seq( "000012340023", "000123400023", "001234000230", "012340002300", "123400002300" ).toDF("cols")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [cols: string]

scala> df.show()
+------------+
|        cols|
+------------+
|000012340023|
|000123400023|
|001234000230|
|012340002300|
|123400002300|
+------------+

scala> df.withColumn("newCols", removeLeadingZerosUDF($"cols")).show()
+------------+------------+
|        cols|     newCols|
+------------+------------+
|000012340023|    12340023|
|000123400023|   123400023|
|001234000230|  1234000230|
|012340002300| 12340002300|
|123400002300|123400002300|
+------------+------------+
```